# Angular 4 Expression Changed After It Has Been Checked Error

Tags: angular

Im get this error `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.` from the reactiveform after check if the form is valid.

**creatForm**

```
  public createForm() {
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        this.patternValidator(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)
      ]),
      password: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(6)
      ])
    });
    this.guestForm = new FormGroup({
      guestName: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
      ]),
      guestCode: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8)
      ])
    });
  }
```

**this is the form**

```
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="couplelogin(user)" novalidate>
      <div id="couple_login_form" class="login-form">
        <div class="login-field" [ngClass]="{'pattern' : !loginForm.controls.email.valid && loginForm.controls.email.touched, 'error' : loginForm.controls.email.pristine && loginForm.controls.email.touched, 'focus' : loginForm.controls.email.dirty}">
          <label for="email_login" translate="HOME.EMAIL_FORM">E-Mail</label>
          <input type="email" formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email">
          <div class="message text-center">
            <p translate="HOME.FORM_REQUIRED">This field is required</p>
          </div>
          <div class="pattern text-center">
            <p translate="HOME.ERROR_FORMAT">Enter a valid email.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="login-field" [ngClass]="{'error' : loginForm.controls.password.pristine && loginForm.controls.password.touched, 'focus' : loginForm.controls.password.dirty}">
          <label for="pass_login" translate="HOME.PASSWOR_FORM">Password</label>
          <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password" formControlName="password">
          <div class="message text-center">
            <p translate="HOME.FORM_REQUIRED">This field is required</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="text-center bottom-msg-login" translate="HOME.FORM_MESSAGE">Don't have an account yet? Download the app für Android or iOS, sign in and create your wedding!</p>
        <button class="submit" type="submit" name="couple" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" translate="HOME.LOGIN">Login</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

now, i´m using firebase for the auth of the user, i´m validating the email field with angular 4, but when i make the validation checking if the email formart is correct with firebase the error is gone, any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For validation email you can do this one

```
    'email': [null, [
        Validators.required, Validators.email
    ]],
```

then remove all `[(ngModel)]="user.XXX"` and `name="XXX"`

and change

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="couplelogin(loginForm.value)">
```

Comment: i try to make the validation of the email that way but still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry you were right the problem was the `[(ngModel)]="user.XXX"`, i removed and changed the form to `<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="couplelogin(loginForm.value)">` with out the change the `this.patternValidator(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>(....`